# Magento 2 How to get list of filter for current category using REST API

Tags: magento2, rest-api

How to get a list of filters to show on the category page to allow the customer to filter on products using REST API in Magento 2

Comment: what have you tried? why exactly do you want to use rest?

Comment: at category page on left side has dynamic filter show which based on products , I want that list of filter

Comment: this does not answer my questions. what have you tried?

Comment: I doubt that there is an existing endpoint that provides this information. you will have to write your own